# Solve for $x$ and $y$ where $x^{\prime} = x + y + t$ and $y^{\prime} = 2x - t$. Given $x = 0$, $y = 1$ at $t = 1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the equations 
>   \begin{align}
> x' &= x + y + t \\
> y' &= 2 x - t
> \end{align}
>   with $x(1) = 0$ and $y(1) = 1$, how can solutions be obtained?

I tried solving it but I did not get any idea.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I know ode and pde but I haven't seen this type of problem, don't know how to seperate variables

Comment: Can you solve the following ODE? $$x''-x'-2x=1-t, \qquad x (1)=1, x'(1)=2$$

Comment: Thank you, I solved it

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard approaches.  One is to differentiate the first and plug the second into it.  That gives a second order equation in one variable.  Do you know how to handle those?

The second is to formulate it as a vector equation.  Here it is $$\begin {pmatrix}x\\y \end {pmatrix}'=\begin {pmatrix}1&1\\2&0 \end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix}x\\y \end {pmatrix}+\begin {pmatrix}t\\-t \end {pmatrix} $$
which is like an inhomogeneous first order equation, but working on vector quanties.  You can diagonalize the $2 \times 2$ matrix to make exponentiating it easy.

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to solve it, however second one looks interesting. Can you explain the matrix form of solution

Comment: In analogy to the 1D case $x'=ax$ where the solution is $e^{at}$ we expect the solution to be the exponential of the matrix, which is defined from the Taylor series.  Call the matrix $A$.  If you can write $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ diagonal, then $e^{At}=P^{-1}e^{Dt}P$ and the exponential of a diagonal matrix is the diagonal matrix with the entries exponentiated.

Comment: Thanks a lot ross, can you do the problem in this method to understand it well, pls do it only in your free time, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For $x^{\prime} = x + y + t$ and $y^{\prime} = 2x - t$, Given $x(1) = 0$, $y(1) = 1$, then
\begin{align}
x'' &= x' + y' +1 = x' + 2 x - t + 1.
\end{align}
Now, $x''  - x' - 2 x = 1-t$ has solution $$x(t) = c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{2 t} + \frac{2 t -3}{4}.$$ 
This also leads to
\begin{align}
y(t) &= 2 \int x(u) \, du - \frac{t^{2}}{2} + d_{0} \\
&= - 2 c_{1} \, e^{-t}  + c_{2} \, e^{2 t} - \frac{t^{2} - 3 t}{2} + d_{0}.  
\end{align}
From here one can use the conditions $x(1) = 0$ and $y(1) = 1$ to find the constants. 
This yields 
\begin{align}
0 &= c_{1} e^{-1} + c_{2} e^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \\
1 &= -2 c_{1} e^{-1} + c_{2} e^{2} + 1 + d_{0}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{12} \, \left[ (8 d_{0} + 1) \, e^{- (t-1)} + 2(2d_{0}+1) \, e^{2(t-1)} + 6 t - 9 \right] \\
y(t) &= \frac{1}{6} \, \left[ - (8 d_{0} +1) \, e^{-(t-1)} + (2 d_{0} +1) \, e^{2(t-1)} - 3 t^{2} + 9 t + 6 d_{0} \right].
\end{align}

Since the constant of integration, $d_{0}$, either needs another boundary condition, or can be arbitrary, then consider the case when $d_{0} = 0$ for which the solutions are
\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{12} \, \left[ e^{- (t-1)} + 2\, e^{2(t-1)} + 6 t - 9 \right] \\
y(t) &= \frac{1}{6} \, \left[ - e^{-(t-1)} +  e^{2(t-1)} - 3 t^{2} + 9 t \right].
\end{align}